# Send message to user in Teams / Microsoft Graph SDK C#

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using the Microsoft Graph SDK (Nuget package). I am trying to figure out how to send a message to a specific user in Microsoft Teams (on behalf of the Azure Ad Application). Is this possible? This is the start of my code to find the user I want to send the message to...

```
var tenantId = "TENANT-ID";
var clientId = "Client-ID";
var clientSecret = "SECRET!!";
var userEmailAddress = "my_recipient@test.com";

var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud });

var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(credentials);

var result = await graphServiceClient.Users[userEmailAddress].GetAsync();
```

This code gets the user I'd like to send a private message too, but how can I initiate a private message?

All the answers on Stack seem to be a bit outdated with older versions of the C# SDK or direct REST API communication. I'd really like to use the latest SDK to send a message to a teams user.

Comment: maybe you can try api url `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{chat-id}/messages` which is from [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions-for-chat), it requires `Teamwork.Migrate.All` api permission for client credential flow. And the chat id, you might use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get the chat id. And you can definately using fiddler to capture the chat id. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiCvi.png